# How to collapse an angular tree

Tags: html, angularjs, jsp, requirejs, orientdb

I'm creating a tree. I'm using 2 controllers here. but I can't load the data from the controller. because of the one controller. If I delete that controller data is loading but I can't collapse the tree. If I use that controller tree is collapsing, but the data is not loading..

```
<div ng-controller="projectPorfolioController">
    <ul id="browser" class="filetree">

      <li><span class="folder">Tree</span>
        <ul>

            <li ng-controller="PagesController"><span class="folder">Pages</span>
                <ul><span  class="file" ng-repeat="rol in results">{{rol.name}}</span></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </li> 
    </ul>

    </div>
```

Controller..

```
vtafController.controller('PagesController', [
                    '$scope',
                    '$q',
                    'RESTService',
    function($scope, $q, RESTService) {
                            RESTService.getPages().then(
                                    function(results) {
                                        $scope.results =results;
                                        console.log(results);

                                }, function() {
                                        console.log(Error);
                                    });
                        }   ]);
```

controller 2 (This is that controller, If I delete this data is loading)

```
vtafController.controller('projectPorfolioController', [
                                        '$scope',
                                        '$q',
                                        'RESTService',
                                        function($scope, $q, RESTService) {

                                            // first example
                                            $("#browser").treeview();

                                            // second example
                                            $("#navigation").treeview({
                                                persist: "location",
                                                collapsed: true,
                                                unique: true
                                            });

                                            // third example
                                            $("#red").treeview({
                                                animated: "fast",
                                                collapsed: true,
                                                unique: true,
                                                persist: "cookie",
                                                toggle: function() {
                                                    window.console && console.log("%o was toggled", this);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            // fourth example
                                            $("#black, #gray").treeview({
                                                control: "#treecontrol",
                                                persist: "cookie",
                                                cookieId: "treeview-black"
                                            });

                                        }

                    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your implementation.

Why not placed the two method together in the same controller?

[EDITED] I made a mistake on this
Something like this?

**projectPorfolioController.js**

```
vtafController.controller('projectPorfolioController', ['$scope', '$q', 'RESTService',
 function($scope, $q, RESTService) {
    RESTService.getPages().then(
        function(results) {
            $scope.results = results;
            console.log(results);
        }, function() {
            console.log(Error);
        });
    // first example
    $("#browser").treeview();
    // second example
    $("#navigation").treeview({
        persist: "location",
        collapsed: true,
        unique: true
    });
    // third example
    $("#red").treeview({
        animated: "fast",
        collapsed: true,
        unique: true,
        persist: "cookie",
        toggle: function() {
            window.console && console.log("%o was toggled", this);
        }
    });
    // fourth example
    $("#black, #gray").treeview({
        control: "#treecontrol",
        persist: "cookie",
        cookieId: "treeview-black"
    });
}
}]);
```

**tree.html**

```
<div ng-controller="projectPorfolioController">
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">

  <li><span class="folder">Tree</span>
    <ul>

        <li><span class="folder">Pages</span>
            <ul><span  class="file" ng-repeat="rol in results">{{rol.name}}</span></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
<ul id="navigation" class="filetree">

  <li><span class="folder">Tree</span>
    <ul>

        <li><span class="folder">Pages</span>
            <ul><span  class="file" ng-repeat="rol in results">{{rol.name}}</span></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Remove "ng-controller="PagesController"" from the `<li>`

I am relative new at angularJS but i have been working on a project that uses it for about 3 months or so. Correct me if i am wrong in this assumption but i think that this will work as the loading of data and the jquery manipulation of the div can be all placed in 1 controller file.

Comment: Hey this is working, but if I use another <ul> like this It's not working.

Comment: I have updated my response, please have a look. I intially thought you had only 1 <ul> hence i used the inner controller as an example but looking at the code again you have multiple jquery selector for other <ul>

i have updated my response with another sample <ul> with the selector "#navigation" into the tree.html from your original code.

Comment: Still not working, I don't know why. only one <ul> is working. Can I use a Controller inside another controller? Is there any tutorial?

Comment: Why do you need a controller within a controller?

here's a tutorial that i used when i started learning angularjs
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial